Supabase auth issue
I have a site where I want to have a button, for example, "Add Product," and when clicked, it should trigger an OAuth login with Google and redirect the user to the /dashboard/create URL. Also, I have several protected pages like /dashboard, /dashboard/user/details, etc. I want that if a user tries to access one of these URLs, they should be prompted with the Google OAuth login screen. After logging in, they should be redirected to the URL they initially tried to access (e.g., if they tried to go to /dashboard/user, they should be logged in and land on that page). Currently, I don't know how to achieve this because I'm always redirected to the homepage.
supabase middleware
import { createServerClient } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function updateSession(request: NextRequest) {
  let supabaseResponse = NextResponse.next({
    request,
  });

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return request.cookies.getAll();
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            request.cookies.set(name, value)
          );
          supabaseResponse = NextResponse.next({
            request,
          });
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            supabaseResponse.cookies.set(name, value, options)
          );
        },
      },
    }
  );

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (!user) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    const redirectTo = url.pathname;
    const { data, error: signInError } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: "google",
      options: {
        redirectTo: `http://localhost:3000/auth/callback?redirectTo=${redirectTo}`,
      },
    });

    if (signInError) {
      console.error("Error during sign-in:", signInError.message);
      throw new Error("Failed to sign in with OAuth.");
    }

    if (data?.url) {
      return await NextResponse.redirect(data.url);
    }
  }

  return supabaseResponse;
}


next.js middleware:
import { type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { updateSession } from "@/utils/supabase/middleware";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return await updateSession(request);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // "/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)",
    "/dashboard/:path*",
  ],
};

callback route:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const { searchParams, origin } = new URL(request.url);
  const code = searchParams.get("code");
  console.log("code:", code);
  const next = searchParams.get("next") ?? "/";
  const redirectTo = searchParams.get("redirectTo") ?? "/dashboard/create";

  if (code) {
    const supabase = createClient();
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code);
    if (!error) {
      const forwardedHost = request.headers.get("x-forwarded-host");
      const isLocalEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

      console.log("Origin:", origin);
      console.log("Forwarded Host:", forwardedHost);
      console.log(
        "Redirecting to:",
        isLocalEnv
          ? `${origin}${next}${redirectTo}`
          : `https://${forwardedHost}${next}${redirectTo}`
      );

      if (isLocalEnv) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}${next}${redirectTo}`);
      } else if (forwardedHost) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(
          `https://${forwardedHost}${next}${redirectTo}`
        );
      } else {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}${next}${redirectTo}`);
      }
    }
  }

  // return the user to an error page with instructions
  return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/auth/auth-code-error`);
}

When I use the signIn method as a Next.js server action, it works fine. However, when redirection occurs from protected routes, I always get the error:
"AuthApiError: code challenge does not match previously saved code verifier"
"use server";

import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { SupabaseClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

export default async function signIn() {
  const supabase: SupabaseClient = createClient();

  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: "google",
    options: {
      redirectTo: `http://localhost:3000/auth/callback`,
    },
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error("Error during sign-in:", error.message);
    throw new Error("Failed to sign in with OAuth.");
  }

  console.log("data url", data.url);
  if (data.url) {
    redirect(data.url);
  }
}

I want the user to be logged in on the URL they attempted to access, rather than always being redirected to the homepage. I also want Google login to work when a user tries to access a private route.
Supabase documentation is very sparse, and their examples are terrible.

You are asking multiple things here. You should first attempt to get one part working before trying to do the other. There are multiple working examples of the OAuth flow on the Supabase website, you can also checkout my example project here https://github.com/silentworks/supabase-by-example/tree/main/nextjs. The part about redirecting to the page you started from is just general web development know how, this can be googled.
